# How to use Regex in batch file

Tags: c#, regex, windows, batch-file

I am using batch file in tfs build step.
I wanted to parse a text file from batch script.

File content is something like this

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Changeset: 267406
User: myname
Date: Wednesday, August 12, 2015 5:33:28 PM

Comment:
  TFS Changes

Items:
  edit $/dummyPath/uDClient/PushVersion.bat
  add  $/dummyPath/uDClient/request.json

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Changeset: 267356
User: username
Date: Wednesday, August 12, 2015 12:16:58 PM

Comment:
  Initial check-in

Items:
  edit $/dummyPath/UserControls/Welcome.ascx
  edit $/dummyPath/UserControls/Welcome.ascx.cs
  edit $/dummyPath/UserControls/Welcome.ascx.designer.cs
  deleted $/dummyPath/UserControls/p1.ascx
```

Required out put will be

```
$/dummyPath/uDClient/PushVersion.bat
$/dummyPath/uDClient/request.json
$/dummyPath/UserControls/Welcome.ascx
$/dummyPath/UserControls/Welcome.ascx.cs
$/dummyPath/UserControls/Welcome.ascx.designer.cs
$/dummyPath/UserControls/p1.ascx
```

I wanted to do this parsing in batch script, if it is not possible then i'll go for C# Regex through utility application.

So can anybody suggest me how can i do this in batch script file

I am using below command to get required output

```
for /f "tokens=2" %i  in ('FINDSTR /C:^edit p.txt') do echo %i
```

but i have to run same commond three times (for add,delete also)
in c# regex we can specify list words to match

```
 *(add|delete|edit)\s*
```

How i can use alternate matching words in findstr.

Comment: You should show some effort to solve the problem to get an answer.

Comment: a good starting point is `findstr` -- a command that supports regular expressions; type `findstr /?` for information how it works...

Answer (score 1):

This code with your text in `file.txt` will print the output below it:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=$" %%a in ('find "/" ^<"file.txt"') do echo $%%b
```

**output:**

```
$/dummyPath/uDClient/PushVersion.bat
$/dummyPath/uDClient/request.json
$/dummyPath/UserControls/Welcome.ascx
$/dummyPath/UserControls/Welcome.ascx.cs
$/dummyPath/UserControls/Welcome.ascx.designer.cs
$/dummyPath/UserControls/p1.ascx
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your Response, but i wanted only those file names who was either modified or added (edit | add). This wii give me all the file names

Comment: @PavanTiwari  The `"required out put"` in your question is exactly what is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a Power Shell script to do it.

Here is a powershell script which produces the desired output on your specified input:

```
select-string -Path 'C:\source\source.txt' -Pattern '\$.*' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```